# Graph API: Post permission not valid

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, native

I've developed a windows application that allow users to share image on their facebook profile. It'been in use for a couple of years. The client calls directly the facebook API.

Some days ago I discover that this application doesn't publish images anymore,result of the post action is : 'Requires extended permission publish_actions'.

In this application I use graph API calls and 'publish_actions' permission are setted, as you can see in the URL below.
To obtain the access I use to call this URL: 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=%MYAPPID%&client_id=%MYAPPID%&display=popup&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=code&scope=publish_actions

This URL, until few days ago, allow the users to publish on their walls using their access token.

Are some new permission required to make this post operation?

Thanks

Comment: Did the user grant the permission also? Have you debugged the access token?

Comment: You did get your use of the permission reviewed by Facebook, right?

Comment: As the two comments above state. Has your app been reviewed and approved by Facebook to use publish_actions. Without that permission you won't get to ask a user for the scope. Also did the user grant you permission to publish on their behalf? You can check the permissions they have granted you or debug the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the permission reviewed by Facebook and i set the option for a windows application in developer console and the problem was solved.